# How to fix db2 "value” is too long caused by an XML data value being serialized to the output by XMLSERIALIZE function?

Tags: sql, xml, db2, xmlserializer

how to fix db2 "value” is too long ERROR caused by an XML data value being serialized to the output by XMLSERIALIZE function?

> ERROR : VALUE  IS TOO LONG. SQLCODE=-433, SQLSTATE=22001, DRIVER=4.19.49

```
SELECT      ID, RTRIM(
  REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
      CAST(
        XMLSERIALIZE(
          XMLAGG(
            XMLELEMENT(NAME "Concatenated_Column", E.ColumnA) 
            ORDER BY E.ColumnA
          ) 
          as CLOB(4000)
        ) 
        AS VARCHAR(4000)
      ),
      '<ColumnXML>',''
    ), 
    '</ColumnXML>',','
  )
) as  Output_Concatenated_Column
FROM        TABLE_E E
group by    ID
```

Here Table Name is TABLE_E

ID column : ID (should be primary key/unique in output table)

Column to be concatenated ColumnA - Converting values from Column A into comma separated values.

Example

Input

```
----------    
ID                    Column A
----------
XYZ                   1 
XYZ                   2 
XYZ                   3 
PQR                   1
PQR                   6
PQR                   7
PQR                   6
```

Output

```
----------
ID                       Output_Concatenated_Column
XYZ                      1,2,3
PQR                      1,6,7
```

Comment: I guess you might try to "peel the onion" by removing nesting functions one by one until you get rid of the problem, then do a `DESCRIBE` for that query to see what Db2 knows about the resulting data type. Are you sure all your concatenated elements within each group fit into 10000 bytes? May be use the element name shorter than `"Concatenated_Column"`?

Comment: Thank you! i want to keep it maximum since I am not sure how much data to expect in the concatenated column.

Comment: @mustaccio any suggestions?

Comment: Here is a link i found but not sure how to use here.https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/apsg/src/tpc/db2z_accessxmllobfetchcontinue.html